# I am trying to cast videos from my app to chrome-cast devices

Tags: flutter, dart, video, casting, chromecast

Hi I am trying to cast videos from my flutter app to chromecast devices using this plugin called flutter_video_cast from pub.dev

But the issue is while I am trying to setup these plugin for android. The instruction given by the developers in not clear due to these I am able to use it in my app.

The section which I need clarification is this part

[image]

I am not able to get what it meant by initialize cast context by extending flutter fragement activity.

Any sort of answers will be helpful for me.